# Parse not adding new installs on iOS 8 devices to Data Browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, parse-platform

I am implementing the Pares iOS SDK but am unable to add new installs to the Data Browser. I have seemingly all the correct code and provisioning profiles. I am running iOS 8. What am I missing here?

****EDIT****

I have noticed that on older versions of iOS, devices do seem to be added.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following function to your AppDelegate file.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

My attempt at rewriting it in Objective-C (it's been a while).

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication*) application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: (UIUserNotificationSettings*) notificationSettings {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```